# remove horizontal scroll bar from bootstrap modal-body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to hide horizontal scroll bar on bootstrap modal-body it does hide scroll-bar but my row element content is hidden inside the modal , How can hide `scroll-x` on bootstrap modal-body and wrap all text into row ?

modal.html

```
<div  class="modal-body disableHorizontalScroll">
    <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-md-12">-->
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th st-ratio="20">File Name</th>
                        <th st-ratio="80">Logged Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages" st-ratio="90">
                        <td st-ratio="20">{{item.filename}}</td>
                        <td st-ratio="80">{{item.value}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

main.css

```
.disableHorizontalScroll {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: You might need to show a js fiddle or code snippet for this.  I tried your same code and it successfully hid the `overflow-x`.  I of course did not have your data but I manually entered in a long string for each `td` and it had no problem hiding it.

Comment: Don't have access to js fiddle and other sites I was able to hide horizontal scroll but some part of my data is also hidden

Comment: Obviously you know this now, but using `overflow-x: hidden` will hide any overflow.  It's not really clear what you current situation looks like and so it's difficult to help you.  If you have long strings that are too long to fit in your table cells then you have two choices, make the strings shorter somehow, either by shrinking font size or inserting line breaks, or make the table cells wider.  I'm happy to try to help, but I'm not sure what your working with.